# Good solutions to keep graphs (database)

Tags: mongodb, graph, redis, database, nosql

I'm developing dating app for vk.com (it is Russian facebook), so I need to keep social graphs (profiles linked by mutual interests, friends, favorite music, movies, etc). It looks like "user A closest to user B than user C because they have 2 mutual friends and 5 mutual interests VS 1 mutual friend and 4 mutual interests", "user C is closest to ...", etc.
What is good solution for this problem?
I know theory of graphs from math, but I've never worked with graphs in computer science yet (I'm web-developer), I think that this problem can be solved by generating graph for any user and keeping it in NoSQL database (like mongo or redis), but it is bad solution (no realtime changes, generation will take long time).
What you think about this problem?

Comment: I don't know much about them, but I know that for accessing facebook data they use it's API. So try checkint VKontakte's API: http://vk.com/developers.php

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not about api, it is about how to keep graph data structure in any database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you could consider is [FlockDB](https://github.com/twitter/flockdb) (Neo4j has already been mentioned) by Twitter. If your problem space is simple queries on a large scale this might be suitable. It doesn't support graph walking queries like Neo does, but is used by Twitter to store their social graph and supports queries such as 'Who does A follow' etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are more specialised NoSQL solutions than key-value based databases. Take a look at graph databases like [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/). Graph databases will easily let you store and manipulate your graph in an intuitive way. Many graph based algorithms will run really fast (compared to sql).

You should also take a look at how the big social networks do it, especially if you are interested in analysing the whole graph (for data mining, that goes beyond real time calculations for single users). As far as I know, facebook uses heavily cached MySQL databases for web requests and Hadoop/HBase and Hive for heavy calculation with the data. Besides their messaging platform, most real-time parts of facebook don't require NoSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't think Facebook stores their main data in a graph database.  I think they store lists of friends and lists of interests, etc. Looking at their documentation will at least show you how it's organized.  If the information "I like movies" is associated with my account and with the interest "movies", it's easy to lookup what I like and who also likes movies.

To compute overall "closeness".... if you only need this for people with at least one common friend, evaluating all such people directly for closeness might be fast enough.  Otherwise, I would consider looking at a higher dimensional approximate k-d tree search, making intests into dimensions in your search space.